# lock table in multiple session insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a testing procedure who very often insert results in the table. When I'll run the same procedure in different sessions ( tabs pl / sql developer ), I can lock the table ? To sum up whether doing only that inserts in different sessions can I lock the table which will interrupt the procedures ?

I can not find an answer to my question I would be grateful for an explanation or a link to a similar topic.

Comment: sorry, hard to read that grammar, are you asking if locking a table interrupts another session? (if so, No it won't "interrupt" it .. whoever has the lock first will hold it until it's finished - other sessions will wait (or fail depending on options used))   - not that my grammar is much better ;)

Comment: sorry for my english, I mean the 'inserts' in different sessions on the same time can add data to the same table who does not have constraints

Comment: Inserts usually don't lock the table, so they shouldn't impact other sessions. If you have a specific example (including table creation, constraints - if any (you indicated none), and some example statements) ..  but based on what you've indicated so far, It sounds like they won't impact each other.

Comment: I read the documentation that the ' insert ' implies ' row exclusive lock' from here my fears,  nnfortunately I do not have with me the code , but it is a simple procedure deploys in different sessions for different tables adds several records with metadata on one target table

Comment: yes, an insert will technically "lock" that row (but not the table), so nobody else can touch that "row" until you're done with it. However, they can certainly insert another "row" .. which they will have a lock on themselves (and you can't touch it - it's "their" row) ...